# Nginx configured with http2 doesn't deliver HTTP/2

Tags: nginx, openssl

I have a problem with my Nginx configuration. I upgraded to nginx 1.9.6 to test http/2 but it does not work on my server.

I used ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS

This is the nginx -V output :

```
nginx version: nginx/1.9.6
built with OpenSSL 1.0.2d 9 Jul 2015
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --prefix=/etc/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --with-pcre-jit --with-debug --with-http_addition_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_geoip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_image_filter_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_xslt_module --with-http_v2_module --with-stream --with-ipv6 --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --with-openssl=/build/nginx-GFP362/nginx-1.9.6/debian/openssl-1.0.2d --add-module=/build/nginx-GFP362/nginx-1.9.6/debian/modules/nginx-auth-pam --add-module=/build/nginx-GFP362/nginx-1.9.6/debian/modules/nginx-echo --add-module=/build/nginx-GFP362/nginx-1.9.6/debian/modules/nginx-upstream-fair --add-module=/build/nginx-GFP362/nginx-1.9.6/debian/modules/nginx-dav-ext-module --add-module=/build/nginx-GFP362/nginx-1.9.6/debian/modules/nginx-cache-purge
```

And this is my vhost config :

```
server {
    listen         80;
    server_name    localhost;
    return         301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied

    root /var/www/rendez-vous;
    index index.phtml index.html index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name localhost;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certificates/myeventsportal/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certificates/myeventsportal/server.key;

/...
```

If I navigate to my site with the latest version of chrome, it is only served over http/1.1.

Comment: Have you checked the caveats section on https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-1-9-5/

Comment: Did you wipe your browser cache? Try from an Incognito Window.

Comment: The incognito Window change nothing. I read the caveat section and the only part is the `ssl_prefer_server_ciphers` but i have not handshake error

Comment: This is caused by the header sent from the web server is your web server configured to send HTTP/2.0

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I've just run into the same problem, but I think I know why it happens. nginx 1.9.6 is not a stock package on Ubuntu 14.04, so you're probably getting it from an [nginx PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Enginx/+archive/ubuntu/development). That's fine, but those packages are built with the stock libraries from 14.04, which is to say OpenSSL 1.0.1f. Unfortunately that version of OpenSSL does not contain [RFC7301](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7301) [ALPN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application-Layer_Protocol_Negotiation) support which is needed for proper HTTP/2 negotiation; it only supports the now-deprecated NPN. It looks like Chrome has already removed support for NPN, so it's incapable of negotiating an HTTP/2 connection without ALPN. Firefox 41 on the other hand, still has NPN support and you should be able to use HTTP/2 with that.

You can test your server like this - you will need OpenSSL 1.0.2d installed on your client (run `openssl version` to check):

Test with ALPN:

```
echo | openssl s_client -alpn h2 -connect yourserver.example.com:443 | grep ALPN
```

If ALPN is working, you should see:

```
ALPN protocol: h2
```

otherwise you'll get:

```
No ALPN negotiated
```

Test with NPN:

```
echo | openssl s_client -nextprotoneg h2 -connect yourserver.example.com:443
```

If that works, you will get:

```
Next protocol: (1) h2
No ALPN negotiated
```

That means that it's successfully negotiating an HTTP/2 connection via NPN, which is what Firefox does.

So how to solve this? The only way I can see is to install a later build of openssl from a PPA (I use [this one](https://launchpad.net/%7Eondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php) for PHP, which also contains openssl) and build your own nginx linked to it. You can find the config params for your existing nginx build by running `nginx -V`, and you should be able to use that to build your own version.

**Update**: I've discovered that the reason that Chrome doesn't support HTTP/2 with NPN is not that it doesn't support NPN (though it will be dropped at some point), but that it specifically doesn't support h2 with NPN, as shown on the chrome://net-internals/#http2 page:

[image: Chrome HTTP/2 info]

Comment: I just noticed that you are already running openssl 1.0.2d - but the tests may still prove useful.

Comment: My nginx package is compiled with the latest openssl version but ubuntu 14.04 has an outdated version. If i remember, it's the 1.0.1f

Comment: Yes, that's what I said.

Comment: For the first command, i got an error `unknown option -alpn` and the second command works fine

Comment: That means you're not running an openssl 1.0.2d client. Install one and it will work. FWIW, I've just rebuilt nginx from the PPA and it's now working perfectly for me.

Comment: Thank you for providing such concrete information and testing methods. Recompiling nginx against 1.0.2h got things up and running.

Comment: What's the status of this now, at the edge of 2016? I still see nginx not serving files as HTTP2

Comment: Check your versions. Stock packages on 14.04 will still be too old and require a manual build. Later Ubuntu releases should fare better.

Comment: Provided link 'this one' is not working.

Comment: Thank you: I used this PPA to install Nginx w/ the updated openssl and it is working for me: https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/nginx

Comment: My nginx :
nginx/1.12.2
OPENSSL: OpenSSL 1.1.0h  27 Mar 2018
NO ALPN

Answer (score 3):

**Short version.**

I found that ESET antivirus can prevent HTTP/2 from working when SSL/TLS filtering is turned on, on the browsing computer. Check to see that your antivirus is not filtering the SSL/TLS.

---

**TLDR version**

I ran into the same problem as the poster, but with an interesting twist. I upgraded my server configuration to nginx 1.12.1. compiled with OpenSSL 1.0.2.g and on initial inspection it had “solved” the problem of HTTP/2 not working. In my browser, I could see that the server certificate was verified by Let’s Encrypt. Content was also being served with HTTP/2.

Some time later, I found that the very same page and same resources were no longer being served over HTTP/2. Coincidentally, the site was no longer verified by Let’s Encrypt, but by Eset?!!?! To my amazement, the new http2 problem had nothing to do with my server configuration at all. It turned out that I had SSL/TLS filtering on in my antivirus on my local computer and this was causing the issue. The solution was to turn off SSL/TLS filtering in the antivirus. Once I had turned it off (and rebooted the computer) HTTP/2 worked again and the certificate was verified by Let’s Encrypt again.

For instructions on how to turn off SSL/TLS in ESET, check out http://support.eset.com/kb3126/?locale=en_US

Comment: This was the issue in my case. Saved me from insanity as it was working in one browser(which was not filtered by firewall) but not in any other

Comment: You are a super genius. It was ESET and I had spent my 4 days in finding the problem. I just tried everything possible in this world of Linux. I just can't believe it was ESET and I was hammering my VPS.

Comment: I have opened a support ticket at https://forum.eset.com/topic/17640-eset-is-filtering-ssltls-traffic-thus-downgrading-latest-http2-protocol/

Answer (score 1):

As Synchro says in his answer, the issue is most nginx packages are not built with OpenSSL 1.0.2. [Compilation of ALPN requires symbols](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/4f578bfcab740fcfbbb8824822803ad9b3f176cc/src/http/modules/ngx_http_ssl_module.c#L320) only present in the relevant OpenSSL development source.

You could try using the [official nginx distribution](http://nginx.org/en/linux_packages.html#mainline), selecting xenial rather than trusty. This works for me with Debian Jessie and jessie-backports OpenSSL 1.0.2 - it may work for you. However, be aware that it is an unsupported configuration - rebuilding it is the "right" answer.